# How to plot a matrix in f#?

Tags: matrix, plot, 3d, f#

I'm trying to plot a NxM Matrix in f# in a way that each coordinate is ploted against it's value. For 2d plots I just use the Fsharp.Charting package. Unfortunately, the package doesn't support 3d plots. Further, every solution I found on the net seems to work with functions (x,y) -> f(x,y).

Does anyone know how to do it? I link to a tutorial or something would be usefull.

Comment: Generally speaking, asking for an off-site resource is off-topic for stackoverflow. If you need more general resources for a topic, the tag wiki is generally a good starting point (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/f%23/info) and for F# in particular, F# for fun and profit (http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work-5/) is a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on R (the statistical language) but my understanding is that it's good at plots.  And there's an F# type provider for it...